# php autocommit FALSE

Tags: php, mysqli, autocommit

when I do in a php file something like this:

```
$mysqli->autocommit(FALSE);
$mysqli->multi_query($sqlCombined);
$mysqli->autocommit(TRUE);
```

Does the commit stops the whole database or just the thread that is running my php program?
I mean, if another user at the same time is doing an update with a different php program that does not use autocommit(fase/true) will the database do the commit?

Comment: i think this is depending on your tables engines , it maybe helpful to provide the types of your table engine .

Comment: Test it with: `select @@autocommit;` in another script. But its session (if changed via php) based, not global (global comes from mysql conf) in mysql. Read more https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_autocommit